# Crypto-JS AES file encryption and decryption is incredibly slow

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, wsh

I am writing a script to encrypt and decrypt files using the crypto-js library and the windows script host. However when i try to encrypt an image file that is 1.5mb in size, it takes upwards of 30 seconds to encrypt. And decryption takes much much longer, so long that I haven't been able to wait it out without killing the process.

Are there ways I should be improving the efficiency of my code, or am I fundamentally encrypting the file in the wrong way.

Cheers for any advice. :)

```
function encryptFile (file, encryptionKey) {
  try {
    var fileReader = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fileReader.CharSet = '437';
    fileReader.Open();
    fileReader.LoadFromFile(file);
    WScript.Echo("beginning crypt"); // debugging
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileReader.ReadText(), encryptionKey);
    WScript.Echo("finished crypt"); // debugging
    fileReader.Close();
    return encrypted;
  } catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}

function decryptFile (file) {
  try {
    var fileReader = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fileReader.CharSet = '437';
    fileReader.Open();
    fileReader.LoadFromFile(file);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(fileReader.ReadText(), KEY);
    fileReader.Close();
    var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return plaintext;
  } catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: WScript? You definitely can’t use anything more appropriate than JavaScript on WSH for this? Node.js has built-in AES that would be much faster, for example, or you could use .NET, or Python, or C…

Comment: Its a proof of concept for these platforms in particular :)

Comment: Well, you are successfully proving that WSH is not the right platform for this concept…

Comment: Thanks I guess...

Comment: Hopefully someone can help with the actual problem of encrypting large files with AES. :/

Comment: The answer remains “use anything else”. Shell out to it from WSH if you have to, but you need some external tool, because JScript is never going to be fast enough. Are you able to install Node? Or even just the OpenSSL set of tools?